# Using Hook_form_alter on webform submitted values

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform, hook-form-alter

Drupal 7. Webforms 3.x.

I am trying to modify a webform component value on submit.  I made a custom module called 'mos' and added this code to it.

```
function mos_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_43') {
      dsm($form['#node']->{'webform'}['components']['1']);
      $form['#submit'][] = 'mos_contact_us_submit';
    }
}
function mos_contact_us_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#node']->{'webform'}['components']['1'] = 'working@mos.com';
}
```

However when I look at the results in the database the regular, non-overridden value is stored.  Can you help let me know what I am doing wrong?

Eventually I want to take the input value and output an email address based on what was provided (for example. 24 turns into bob@somewhere.com) But I think I can figure this part out myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to place your submit first.

```
array_unshift(
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 
      'mos_contact_us_submit'
);
```

However, if you want to change some variables in form_state, you should to using custom _valadate function.

Comment: Is custom_validate referring to the [Webform Validation Module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation) or some other function in drupal/webform standard? Thanks for the reply, I'll see where I get with array_unshift.

Comment: Hi @dobeerman, array_unshift gives me this error. 
_Warning: array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in mos_form_alter() (line 24 of ...module_

New code
`function mos_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ('webform_client_form_43' == $form_id) {
  array_unshift(
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 
    'mos_check_email'
 );

  }
}

function mos_check_email(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {`

Comment: $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array('mos_contact_us_submit');

Comment: This should have been $form[#submit] instead of $form['actions']['submit']['#submit']

Answer (score 0):

I got it!  BIG Thanks to @dobeerman for pointing me in the right direction. Here is the code that ended up working:

```
function mos_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ('webform_client_form_43' == $form_id) {
    //dsm($form);
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mos_check_email';   
  }
}

function mos_check_email(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $emailVal = $form_state['values']['submitted']['to'];
    switch($emailVal) {
        case 1: $emailVal = 'email@test.com'; break;
        case 2: $emailVal = 'email2@test.com'; break;
        case 3: $emailVal = 'email3@test.com'; break;
                ......
    }
    $form_state['values']['submitted']['to']=$emailVal;
    //dpm($form_state);
}
```

This way I can keep email address private, but still pass variables to the form with _GET. Kind of a weird situation... but we are trying to keep some existing code intact, so it seemed like the best route.

I accidentally messed up my account creation, so I can't give you the credit dobeerman but I emailed the admins and hopefully I will get it straightened out to get you some rep!

Comment: I don't know why, but when I change values in $form_state, they are not changed in the form when there is an error

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the code. But my first guess would be that your custom validation function never got to run. In my example above I add my function to the validation array, which means it runs after whatever validation was in place.  If one of the previous validation functions does not complete (error), I don't believe the later validation functions even execute.