# How to create a custom module from Webforms in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have a form that I am aiming to submit to paypal payment.

I have tried several options like the Paypal API and the like but I can't seem to get the hang of it since the requirement of what I am doing is pretty simple.

Right now I have a form and I am using Webforms to build it. I am well aware that webforms has its default value for action attribute which is not so easy to alter.

Also, the names for the inputs appear to be something like:
      name="submitted[last_name]"

To be direct, I would like to change the actions url of the webform and then the field names from to simply name="last_name"

Is there a simple way to do it? If there is, I would appreciate your suggestion.

Also, if what I assume based on my reading that it is not possible, I have read in this question ([Using Hook_form_alter on webform submitted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560133/using-hook-form-alter-on-webform-submitted-values)) that I can create a custom module based on webform and make the changes there. The problem is that I am new to drupal and I am still trying to understand how to make things work and I have no idea how to start or create the custom module based on webforms. Is it just simply copying the whole files in webforms then replace all occurences of webforms to my custom module name?

Answer (score 0):

You dont create a module from webforms, instead the usual practice is to hook in to specific form from another module.
Basicly you need 1 folder and 2 files in there, eg mymodule folder and mymodule.info + mymodule.module . Good place to place those would be sites/all/modules/custom/ under your installation directory.

Read the description about .info file at https://www.drupal.org/node/542202

You can connect to webforms in many ways but the standard way in most form tampering cases start with hook_form_alter. Your module could start with something like this

```
<?php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  /* find and tamper with $form here
     install devel and then uncomment the following */
  //dpm($form);
}
```