# Drupal 7: Webform: Send Emails Conditionally?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

Is there any way to put a condition for sending emails?

For example: on my webform, I want to send email out only when current user = 'xyz' ?

I searched a lot but could not find a way to send email conditionally..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Webform Rules](https://drupal.org/project/webform_rules) is what you are looking for.

Other option is to do it programatically. Check the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560133/using-hook-form-alter-on-webform-submitted-values).

EDIT:

Event:

1. After a webform has been submitted

Condition:

1. Select data comparison
2. Click on the field, a dropdown will appear
3. Select Use:...(User, who submitted the webform)
4. This will open up a new dropdown. Select the data you want to match. In your case, it will be user:name
5. Click continue. Configure "equals", "Data value" = XYZ.

Action:

1. Send Email.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am not getting an idea on how to send email based on a condition. Can you point me to a working example?

Comment: One more thing fortuzlab. If I want to add another condition for one of the field on that form, how do I do that?
So for example, it could be like fieldx = 'abc' then send email instead of user 'xyz'

Comment: I am afraid conditions do not provide fields in the selector. It does provide a data object though. You might need to write a custom php snippet to get the fields from the object.

Comment: Use Show message on site the examine the $data object. This is the data that is sent on the webform. Look at the components values. Using this and some PHP you can set a condition for who gets the email.